# What's the most elegant way to check if any item from a list is inside another list in Python?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

```
a = ["one", "two", "three"]
b = ["three two", "four", "five"]
```

I just want to check if any element of list a is found within any elements of b, as a boolean result. Is there a more elegant way than having to loop both lists?

In this case, "three" is found in "three two", so it returns True.

Comment: Other than looping and breaking when a match is found, how else would you know without checking element by element?

Comment: if "threetwo", would this return true?

Comment: @hgb123 Yes, it would.

Comment: @Chris maybe there is some built-in function in python.

Comment: @JoanVenge my point is that even if there were a function, in the background it'd still be looping.

Comment: Oh yes of course. I mean without me looping, that's what I mean.